# From the terminal verify if python 3 is installed

Tags: bash, python-3.x, terminal

I am writing a shell script, and before the script runs I want to verify that the user has Python 3 installed. Does anyone know or have any ideas of how I could check that, and the output be a boolean value?

Comment: `which python3` and check the exit code?

Comment: @MartijnPieters `which` is slow and unreliable

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick: how is it unreliable *for executable files* (`python3` will never be a built-in)? I can see that `command` is a little faster, but I'd hardly call 3 ms for `which python3` to be 'slow', either.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### Interactive shell

Simply run `python3 --version`. You should get some output like `Python 3.8.1` if Python 3 is installed.

#### Shell script

You can use the `command` or `type` builtins:

```
command -v python3 >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo Python 3 is installed  # POSIX-compliant
type -P python3 >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo Python 3 is installed     # Bash only
```

Using `which` is not recommended as it requires launching an external process and might give you incorrect output in [some cases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86029/903).

Answer (score 5):

execute the following command.
`which python3` and check the exit status of the command `$?`. it will be 0 if user has python 3 installed, 1 otherwise.

Comment: May want to redirect &>/dev/null as Eugene does above if you want to silence the error.

Answer (score 4):

You can check it with regular expression match, on the "python3 -V" output.

For example:

```
[[ "$(python3 -V)" =~ "Python 3" ]] && echo "Python 3 is installed"
```

Comment: This approach throws an error if it is not installed